# Adding an object in Java

Tags: java

I'm not getting any errors but I couldn't add Course

```
    //in my Course class i use equals method to check whether they are the sam
    public boolean equals (Course other){
    Course c = (Course) other;
    if(c != null){
        if (this.name.equals(c.name) && this.instructor.equals(c.instructor) && this.numberOfSection == (c.numberOfSection) && this.year == (c.year))
            return true;
        else
            return false;   
        }
    else 
        return false;
}

//in my CourseCatalog class i use the equals method in Course and if they are not same 
// i add the course to the catalog
public void addCourse (Course other) {
    if(other != null){
        if( !other.equals(course1) && !other.equals(course2) && !other.equals(course3) && !other.equals(course4))
        {
            if (noOfCourse == 0){
                course1 = new Course(other);
                noOfCourse ++;
            }
            if (noOfCourse == 1){
                course2 = new Course(other);
                noOfCourse ++;
            }
            if (noOfCourse == 2){
                course3 = new Course(other);
                noOfCourse ++;
            }
            if(noOfCourse == 3){
                course4 = new Course(other);
                noOfCourse ++;
            }   
        }
    }
}

            //the following code is what i do in the tester class 
            CourseCatalog myCourseCatalog  = new CourseCatalog();
    Course course1 = new Course();
    course1.setName("Math101");
    course1.setInstructor("Jack Smith");
    course1.setYear(2007);
    course1.setNumberOfSection(3);
    myCourseCatalog.addCourse(course1);

            // i add a different course 
    Course course2 = new Course("Cs101", "David Brown", 2003 ,3);
    myCourseCatalog.addCourse(course2);
    Course copyCourse = new Course(course2);
    myCourseCatalog.addCourse(copyCourse);
```

However the program prints out in this way;

```
Name: Math101
Instructor: Jack Smith
Year: 2007
Number Of Sections: 3Name: Math101
Instructor: Jack Smith
Year: 2007
Number Of Sections: 3Name: Math101
Instructor: Jack Smith
Year: 2007
Number Of Sections: 3Name: Math101
Instructor: Jack Smith
Year: 2007
Number Of Sections: 3
```

So that means i cannot addcourse why?  I'm a new student in java so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Put in the code where you are iterating over the `myCourseCatalog` and printing the `Course`

Comment: here is the printing info method in course class;               public String printInfo(){
  String sentence = "";
  sentence += "Name: " + name + "\n";
  sentence += "Instructor: " + instructor + "\n";
  sentence += "Year: " + year + "\n";
  sentence += "Number Of Sections: " + numberOfSection + "\n"; 
  return sentence;
 }

Comment: and be sure to include the code where noOfCourse is defined and any modifications to it's value before calling your addCourse method.

Comment: public void printContents(){
  String a = course1.printInfo();
  String b = course2.printInfo();
  String c = course3.printInfo();
  String d = course4.printInfo();
  if ( noOfCourse > 0){
   System.out.print(a);
  } 
  if (noOfCourse > 1){
   System.out.print(b);
  }
  if (noOfCourse > 2){
   System.out.print(c);
  }
  if (noOfCourse > 3){
   System.out.print(d);
  }
 }

Comment: you have got the answers i suppose, just a suggestion try using one of the collection classes, that way you will not have to worry about these things.

Comment: yes yes i fix the problem, what type of classes do you mean?

Comment: try looking out for arraylist or linked list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this is a beauty...

You are using a chain of if-else which makes sure that all the `if` are true and gets executed. In first `if` you check for `noOfCourse == 0` and then increment it; in the next one you check for `noOfCourse==1` which will be true due to the increment.

**So when you call you method `addCourse` first time all courses are already set.**

Please Replace

```
if (noOfCourse == 0){
    course1 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if (noOfCourse == 1){
    course2 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if (noOfCourse == 2){
    course3 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if(noOfCourse == 3){
    course4 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
```

with

```
if (noOfCourse == 0){
    course1 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if (noOfCourse == 1){
    course2 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if (noOfCourse == 2){
    course3 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if(noOfCourse == 3){
    course4 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
```

Comment: me too; man! All the best... Accept the answer which helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're actually having a cascading `if` problem. See below...

```
if (noOfCourse == 0){
    course1 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if (noOfCourse == 1){
    course2 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if (noOfCourse == 2){
    course3 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
if(noOfCourse == 3){
    course4 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
```

No matter what `noOfCourse` is, it will increment it, thus satisfying the `if` immediately below it. This causes your course to fill multiple course slots. The solution is to use `else if`.

```
if (noOfCourse == 0){
    course1 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if (noOfCourse == 1) {
    course2 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if (noOfCourse == 2) {
    course3 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
} else if (noOfCourse == 3) {
    course4 = new Course(other);
    noOfCourse ++;
}
```

This way, it will only add the course *once*. :-)

By the way, you should really use an array or `List` here.

```
final Count[] courses = new Course[4];
final int coursesAssigned = 0;
...
if (coursesAssigned < 4) {
  courses[coursesAssigned++] = new Course(other);
}
```

Additionally, why are you copying `other`?

Comment: @YigitCan why not use an array or `List`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html o is that what you're saying? I don't know actually such classes that's why I'm coding every single line in my programs

Comment: @YigitCan yes, you can keep all your courses in an array or `List` rather than have a separate variable for each slot. PS you should use up-to-date documentation i.e. Java 7 (1.7) not 1.4.2.